# how can i solve this when i try to return a 2d struct from a function

Tags: c, struct

this is how i declare this struct

```
typedef struct cache{
int vaild;
char* tag;
char* data;
}cache;
```

this is part of my main which called this function

```
struct cache **cacheA = createCache(Setnum,(int)pow(2,blocksize),cachesize);
struct cache **cacheB = createCache(Setnum,(int)pow(2,blocksize),cachesize);
```

and now this is my called function

```
struct cache ** createCache(int numset, int blocksize, int cachesize){
    int numcache = (int)((cachesize/blocksize)*numset);
    struct cache out[numset][numcache];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < numset; i++){
        for (j=0; j < numcache; j++){
            out[i][j].tag = "0";
            out[i][j].vaild = 0;
            out[i][j].data ="0";
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

and when i try to compile this, it tells me that

```
return from incompatible pointer type 
function returns address of local variable
```

(which points to the line "return out;")

I have no idea whats wrong with my code, i mean the type of the function return is the same as how i declear "out", so what causes this problem?

Comment: `out` is local to `createChache`'s scope, if you return a pointer to it that pointer will be dangling the moment it's returned as `out` will have been destroyed.

Comment: The other mention concerns that `struct cache **` is not the same type of object as `struct cache out[numset][numcache];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create            `struct cache out[numset][numcache];`
within the function prototyped as: `struct cache ** createCache(...)`.
Then attempt to return `out`.

It is because `struct cache [][]` is typed differently than `struct cache **` that you are getting the return errors.

Other comments:
1) If you truly do want a pointer to pointer to struct, then malloc or calloc will need to be used at some point to allocate memory.
2) the char * members of the struct also need to be assigned memory before assigning values. For illustration below, they are changed to `char []`
3) assigning values to strings does not work by using = assignment operator. Use a string function such as `strcpy`, `sprintf`, etc.
4) you've named the struct with the same symbol as that of the new type you have created, i.e. `cache`. In this application, the name cache is not necessary.  Also, purely for style, I show the new type in CAPS.  *This is not necessary*, but just a style I use to make the new type more recognizable in code.

In consideration of the comments above, the struct could be changed to the following:

```
typedef struct { /// don't need name here when it in this application
    int vaild;
    //char *tag;
    char tag[20];//for illustration, to avoid additional dynamic allocation of memory
    //char* data;
    char data[80];
}CACHE;//capitalization is style only, not a necessity here.
```

Note, there is no name, but the new type `CACHE` was created.  Now, you can create the function createCache:

```
CACHE ** createCache(int ncache, int nset)//note for simplicity of freeing this 
                                          //object later, simplify number of arguments
{
    CACHE **out;
    out = calloc(ncache, sizeof(CACHE *));//create array of pointers to CACHE
    if(!out) return NULL;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < nset; i++)
    {
        out[i] = calloc(nset, sizeof(CACHE));//create space for each instance 
                                             //of CACHE pointed to by array pointers
    }
    return out;
}
```

Anytime memory is created on the heap, it needs to be freed.  This method will free the CACHE object memory:

```
void freeCashe(CACHE **a, int nset)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<nset; i++)
    {
        if(a[i])free(a[i]); 
    }
    if(a)free(a);
}
```

Calling these functions as shown below, will create an array of pointers, each pointing to an instance of `CACHE` where you can use them as intended, then free all of the memory when finished:

```
int main(void)
{
    int cachesize = 20;
    int blocksize = 20;
    int numset   = 10;
    //move the calculation out of creation function
    //to simplify freeing object later.
    int numcache = (int)((cachesize/blocksize)*numset);

    CACHE **a = createCache(numcache, numset);
    /// use a, then free a
    freeCashe(a, numset);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to allocate the memory on the heap rather than the stack. You will need to allocate space on the heap for your array of pointers, and for what they point too.

```
struct cache ** createCache(int numset, int blocksize, int cachesize){
    cache ** out;
    int numcache = (int)((cachesize/blocksize)*numset);
    size_t headerSize = sizeof(*out)*numset;
    size_t bodySize = sizeof(**out)*numcache;
    out = malloc(headerSize + (bodySize*numset));
    if (out == NULL) {
        /* Should probably output some message about being 
         * insufficient memory here. */
        return NULL;
    }

    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < numset; i++){
        /* need to assign our point */
        out[i] = (cache*)(((char*)out)+(headerSize+bodySize*i));
        for (j=0; j < numcache; j++){
            out[i][j].tag = "0";
            out[i][j].vaild = 0;
            out[i][j].data ="0";
        }
    }
    return out;
}

/* importantly, you want a way to free your allocated memory */
void destroyCache(cache ** ptr) {
    free(ptr);
}
```

PS: You don't have to `typedef` your struct if you reference it with the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting a pointer pointer type to be returned, but in order to do that you need to dynamically allocate it. Local stack allocations (i.e. struct cache[x][y]) won't work. You will either get an error or your program will crash when attempting to use the 2D array.

The solution is to either pre-allocate space and pass it in to the function or allocate in the function itself.

Allocation In Function Example:

```
struct cache ** createCache(int numset, int blocksize, int cachesize){
    int numcache = (int)((cachesize/blocksize)*numset);

    struct cache **out = malloc(sizeof(struct cache *) * numset); // This line changed.
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i < numset; i++){

        out[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct cache) * numcache); // This line added.

        for (j=0; j < numcache; j++){

            out[i][j].tag = malloc(sizeof(char)); // This line added.
            out[i][j].data = malloc(sizeof(char)); // This line added.

            strcpy(out[i][j].tag, "0");
            out[i][j].vaild = 0;
            strcpy(out[i][j].data, "0");
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget you have to eventually deallocate everything you allocated.